# Pandas DataFrame: info() function for one column only

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe named df_train with 20 columns. Is there a pythonic way to just view info on only one column by selecting its name.

Basically I am trying to loop through the df and extract number of unique values and add missing values

```
print("\nUnique Values:")
for col in df_train.columns:
    print(f'{col:<25}: {df_train[col].nunique()} unique values.  \tMissing values: {} ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the total number of null values, this is the pythonic way to achieve it:

```py
df_train[col].isnull().sum()
```

Comment: beautiful. Thank you

Comment: My pleasure! Please remember to accept the answer if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to select individual columns from a dataframe.

```
df_train['your_column_name']
```

This will extract only the column with <your_column_name>.

PS: This is my first StackOverflow answer. Please be nice.